# Delaying the Submit button click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Jquery and my Question is can i delay the click on the submit button for example, you cannot click the submit button for 1 second after submitting so I can prevent the Click spamming on the submit button

this is my Click event

```
$("#btnConfirmEditNo").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#editContactForm').validationEngine('hide');
        editwnd.close();
    });
```

also tried the `settimeout()` but it delays the closing of the window

Comment: Explore the cool jQuery methods `.one()`, `.on()` and `.off()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example may help you:

### Using On - Off

```js
function handleClick(evt) {
     $( "#btn" ).prop( "disabled", true );
     setTimeout(function() {
       $( "#btn" ).prop( "disabled", false );
       $('#btn').on('click', handleClick);       
     }, 1000);
     $( this ).off( event );     
}

$('#btn').on('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

### Using One

```js
function handleClick(evt) {
     $( "#btn" ).prop( "disabled", true );
     setTimeout(function() {
       $( "#btn" ).prop( "disabled", false );
       $('#btn').one('click', handleClick);       
     }, 1000);     
}

$('#btn').one('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a callback function on a button and subsequently remove that callback using the jquery `off` method.  This means that when the submit button is pressed, you can remove the event handler and then set a timer that will subsequently re-add it after a period of time when the timer fires.  You can use the `window.setTimer()` function to register a function to be called after a period of time.

An alternate algorithm would be to have a class level "flag" that is set when the button is clicked and reset when a timer expires.  In your handler for a button press, you would check the value of the flag and, if true, ignore the button press.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `setTimeout` is used to handle the `1s` *off* state.
Here are two examples:

### Using `.one()`

```
var $btn = $('#btnConfirmEditNo');

function doSomething() {

  // Do here whatever you want

  setTimeout(function(){
    $btn.one("click", doSomething);
  }, 1000);
}

$btn.one("click", doSomething);
```

### Using a *flag*

```
function doSomething() {
  var el = this;
  if(el.noClick) return;
  el.noClick = 1;

  // Do here whatever you want

  setTimeout(function() { el.noClick = 0; }, 1000);
}

$('#btnConfirmEditNo').click(doSomething);
```